# using .reduce() on an a list of objects

Tags: javascript

I have this sample data set:

```
let list = [
  {'first': 'morgan', 'id': 1},
  {'first': 'eric', 'id': 1},
  {'first': 'brian', 'id': 2 },
  {'first': 'derek', 'id' : 2},
  {'first': 'courtney', 'id': 3},
  {'first': 'eric', 'id': 4},
  {'first': 'jon', 'id':4},
]
```

I am trying to end up with this:

```
[[1, [morgan, eric]], [2, [brian, derek]], [3, [courtney]], [4, [eric, jon]]
```

I am using the `.reduce()` function to map over the list. However, I'm somewhat stuck.

I got this working:

```
let b = list.reduce((final_list, new_item) => {
  x = final_list.concat([[new_item.id, [new_item.first]]])
  return x
}, [])
```

However, that flattens out the list into a list of lists of lists, but doesn't combine names that share a similar id.

I tried using `.map()` **the code below does not work**

I tried to map over the final_list (which is a list of [id, [names]] looking to see if the id of the `new_item` exists in the `smaller_list` and then add `new_item.first` to the `smaller_list[1]` (which should be the list of names).

Is this the right approach?

```
let b = list.reduce((final_list, new_item) => {
  final_list.map((smaller_list) => {
    if (smaller_list.indexOf((new_item.id)) >=0) {
      smaller_list[1].concat(new_item.first)
      // not sure what to do here...
    } else {
        // not sure what to do here either...
    }

  })
  x = final_list.concat([[item.id, [item.first]]])
  return x
}, [])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my approach, i'm using reduce to create a sparse array with the index as the list id. I then use `Object.values` to squash it down.

```js
let list = [
  {'first': 'morgan', 'id': 1},
  {'first': 'eric', 'id': 1},
  {'first': 'brian', 'id': 2 },
  {'first': 'derek', 'id' : 2},
  {'first': 'courtney', 'id': 3},
  {'first': 'eric', 'id': 4},
  {'first': 'jon', 'id':4}
];

let result = list.reduce( (acc, item, index) => {
  if(acc[item.id]){
   acc[item.id][1].push(item.first);
  } else {
   acc[item.id] = [item.id, [item.first]];
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to first map over your list and combine the ones with similar ID and then loop over that result in order to change the format to the one requested.

```js
let list = [
  {'first': 'morgan', 'id': 1},
  {'first': 'eric', 'id': 1},
  {'first': 'brian', 'id': 2 },
  {'first': 'derek', 'id' : 2},
  {'first': 'courtney', 'id': 3},
  {'first': 'eric', 'id': 4},
  {'first': 'jon', 'id':4},
]

let temp = [], result = [];

list.map(entry => {
    if(!temp[entry.id]) temp[entry.id] = [entry.first]
    else temp[entry.id].push(entry.first)
})
temp.forEach((names, id) => {
    result.push([id, names])
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

**EDIT:** I used an array as `temp` because the ID is an *integer* and for the convenience of being able to use a `forEach` loop. If the key was something else then you would use a Hash table.

Comment: You sure that `temp` should be an array?

Comment: @Phil I think so because arrays are easier and faster to iterate over than dictionaries and since the id is a integer it's easy to use it as array key .

Comment: Ah, I figured out what was bothering me. `temp` will have an `undefined` entry at position `0`. Seems `forEach` won't include it though or any other gap in the indexes. TIL

Answer (score 3):

Try first creating a map of IDs to names, then map that into your final array, eg

```js
let list = [
  {'first': 'morgan', 'id': 1},
  {'first': 'eric', 'id': 1},
  {'first': 'brian', 'id': 2 },
  {'first': 'derek', 'id' : 2},
  {'first': 'courtney', 'id': 3},
  {'first': 'eric', 'id': 4},
  {'first': 'jon', 'id':4},
]

const idMap = list.reduce((map, item) => {
  if (Array.isArray(map[item.id])) {
    map[item.id].push(item.first)
  } else {
    map[item.id] = [item.first]
  }
  return map
}, {})

const b = Object.keys(idMap).map(id => [parseInt(id), idMap[id]])
console.info(JSON.stringify(b))
```

Comment: I didn't know we had a `console.info`; cool. Nice algorithm too :-)

Answer (score 1):

you want to do it with reduce, and doing it with a single reduce would be nice. here are 3 ways

*verbose, more loops*

```
const tuples1 = list.reduce( (tuples, obj) => {
  if( tuples.some( ( [id, _] ) => id === obj.id ) ){
    tuples.find( ( [id, _] ) => id === obj.id )[1].push(obj.first)
  }else{
    tuples.push([obj.id, [obj.first]])
  }
  return tuples
}, [])
```

*same as tuples1, terse*

```
const tuples2 = list.reduce( (tuples, obj) =>
  ( tuples.some( ( [id, _] ) => id === obj.id ) ) ?
    ( tuples.find( ( [id, _] ) => id === obj.id )[1].push(obj.first), tuples ) :
    ( tuples.push([obj.id, [obj.first]]), tuples ), [])
```

*more verbose, less loops*

```
const tuples3 = list.reduce( (tuples, obj) => {
  const existingId = tuples.find( ( [id, _] ) => id === obj.id )
  if( existingId ){
    existingId[1].push(obj.first)
  }else{
    tuples.push([obj.id, [obj.first]])
  }
  return tuples
}, [])
```

*each produce the same result*

```
[ [ 1, [ 'morgan', 'eric' ] ],
  [ 2, [ 'brian', 'derek' ] ],
  [ 3, [ 'courtney' ] ],
  [ 4, [ 'eric', 'jon' ] ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're also looking for a non `reduce` solution.

Here is one. It is a bit long winded but that is because I'm trying to decompose the problem into a few parts.

1. I first go through the `list` and sort the elements into their respective `Id`.
2. Then For each `id` in the sorted object. I loop through it again by first instantiating an outer element first.
3. Pushed the `id` key into the element first.
4. Loop through all the associated element and extract their `first` property and add it into the nested element.
5. Once the nesting element is been built. I just merge them up into the parent element and attach it into the `result` array.

Hopfully it is not too complicated for you but I suspect it will be easier to see the code in action through an IDE.

```js
var list = [
    {'first': 'morgan', 'id': 1},
    {'first': 'eric', 'id': 1},
    {'first': 'brian', 'id': 2 },
    {'first': 'derek', 'id' : 2},
    {'first': 'courtney', 'id': 3},
    {'first': 'eric', 'id': 4},
    {'first': 'jon', 'id':4},
]

var result = [];
var keyById = {};

// Sort the list of items to be keyed by: Id => [ item, item ]
list.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!keyById.hasOwnProperty(item.id)) {
        keyById[item.id] = [];
    }
    keyById[item.id].push(item);
});

// Build the data structure
for (var id in keyById) {
    var item = []; // The outer element
    var nestedItem = []; // The nested element belonging to the outer
    item.push(id);
    keyById[id].forEach(function(element) {
        nestedItem.push(element.first);
    });
    item.push(nestedItem);
    result.push(item); 
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, '', 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Not very sexy, but it works

- Iterate over `list` and build an object using the `id`s as `key`s with `value`s of `array`s of the `first` names.
- Empty `list` (if you plan to overwrite it).
- Walk through the resultant object making `array`s for each `id` with its next sibling element being an `array` of the names from the `value` associated with that `id`, and `push` them into `list` (or a fresh `array` if maintaining the original `list`).

```js
var list = [
      {'first': 'morgan', 'id': 1},
      {'first': 'eric', 'id': 1},
      {'first': 'brian', 'id': 2 },
      {'first': 'derek', 'id' : 2},
      {'first': 'courtney', 'id': 3},
      {'first': 'eric', 'id': 4},
      {'first': 'jon', 'id':4},
    ],
    o = {}, p;

list.forEach( ( v ) => {
    if ( !o[ v.id ] ) {
        o[ v.id ] = [];
    }
    o[ v.id ].push( v.first );
} );

list = []; // if overwriting

for ( p in o ) {
    if ( o.hasOwnProperty( p ) ) {
        list.push( [ parseInt( p ), o[ p ] ] );
    }
}

console.log( JSON.stringify( list ).replace( /,/g, ", " ) );
```

**Edited** to add `parseInt()` (noticed in another answer) since the question's example expected output does indeed show numerals as integers, not strings.
And changed the demo output to `stringify`ed `JSON` (also noticed (easier to read) in other answers).

Answer (score -2):

It's probably easiest to write a plain loop for this:

```
let final_list = []
for (k = 0; k < list.length; k += 2) {
    let item1 = list[k]
    let item2 = list[k + 1]
    final_list.push([item1.id, [item1.first, item2.first]])
}
```

Comment: This results in *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined"*

Comment: Well, write it correctly then, but the approach is valid.

Comment: No it's not. You're assuming that a) There's always an item after the current index (not true for the last iteration), and b) That the `k + 1` item always has the same ID as the `k` item

Comment: Ah, right. Then the problem is really traversing a list and tabulating names with ids, as @FrenchMajesty did.